# Upgrading from swiper 6 to 9.4.1 , Error: Can't resolve 'swiper/core'

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I am upgrading from swiper 6 to 9.4.1 but i get the `Error: Can't resolve 'swiper/core'` with the `import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/core';` statement , I have files that contain changes from v6 to 9 but these do not seem to be the ones causing the error

I was expecting error associated with the changes from version 6 to 9 but instead the import statement

Comment: Imports can also change between versions... If you're upgrading, I assume you're consulting the [Swiper 9 docs](https://v9.swiperjs.com/get-started)?  Those modules aren't imported from `swiper/core` any more.

Comment: You are upgrading 3 major versions, you need to check the breaking changes. There is probably a lot more that won't work anymore like it used to.